# Setting environment variables in build.gradle.kts

Tags: kotlin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In groovy you can set environment variables with `environment key value`. 
For example for `run` you can do:

```
run {
    environment DB_HOST "https://nowhere"
}
```

How can I accomplish this in Kotlin in build.gradle.kts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this:

```
tasks {
    "run"(JavaExec::class) {
        environment("DB_HOST","https://nowhere")
    }
}
```

Or if you like the delegation property style:

```
val run by tasks.getting(JavaExec::class) {
    environment("DB_HOST","https://nowhere")
}
```

Comment: How can we do that outside of a task?

I would like to use this inside of some `buildSrc` scripts of mine.

Answer (score 5):

I was having trouble setting environment variables during test runs. This worked for me:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    environment("DB_HOST", "https://nowhere")
}
```